# C#: FileStream.SetLength(long) fails with "The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation" (on Windows 10 Home, NTFS)

Tags: c#, large-files, ntfs

I had a very confusing experience with the System.IO.FileStream when writing a fairly large file that was approaching 8Gb in size***.  The call to FileStream.SetLength(LARGE_NUMBER) started to suddenly fail with the error

> The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation

The stacktrace was:

```
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.SetLengthCore(Int64 value)
   at System.IO.FileStream.SetLength(Int64 value)
   at LiteDB.FileDiskService.WriteJournal(ICollection`1 pages, UInt32 lastPageID)
   ...
```

This was reproducible and fairly puzzling as googling turned up no obvious answer.

For the record, the LARGE_NUMBER SetLength was being called with was around 8,110,000,000 -- not small, but not in any way special. I've certainly seen larger files on NTFS before.

---

*** It's a LiteDB database file -- I do recognise I'm probably stretching what it is meant to be used for but this isn't the point of the question.

Answer (score 2):

While I cannot say I have found the exact explanation of what the problem was, I managed to resolve the problem and enable my program to continue extending this file.

I cannot say if this was related, but I noticed a line at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/967351/a-heavily-fragmented-file-in-an-ntfs-volume-may-not-grow-beyond-a-cert saying the following:

> A heavily fragmented file in an NTFS file system volume may not grow beyond a certain size caused by an implementation limit in structures that are used to describe the allocations.

Since I had no other ideas left, I thought I'd try **simply making a copy of the file** and hoping that the copy would end up less fragmented than a file that was written very gradually in small increments over a long time. Amazingly, this worked, and FileStream.SetLength(LARGE_NUMBER) on the copy of the old file started working again.

Interestingly, before I made a copy, I tried renaming the old problematic file and I could not do even that, getting a Windows error popup saying the same thing about the file system limitation.